# Different between !! and true javascript

Tags: javascript

What is different between it

`if(hereIsTrue)` and `if(!!hereIsTrue)`

Comment: There is no difference.

Comment: It's a double negative... it *should* be the same

Comment: if `hereIsTrue` is "truthy" rather than `true`, then `!!hereIsTrue === true` but `hereIsTrue !== true` (note === and !== as opposed to == and !=)